# Is HTTP POST insecure?

Tags: http, man-in-the-middle, brute-force

Is it possible to perform a MITM attack or even bruteforce a HTTP POST?  If so how does one perform an attack and how can a developer protect his/her site from such an attack?

Comment: CSRF. But please do edit your question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Is it possible to perform MITM on HTTP POST?**

HTTP is not encrypted, so if you "get in the middle" you can read the communication and modify it. You can get in the middle by e.g. hacking a router or cutting a cable. Your ISP is already in the middle and can read your HTTP communication.

This is true for all HTTP methods - POST, GET, etc.

**Is it possible to brute-force HTTP POST?**

Since HTTP is not encrypted there is nothing to brute force.

**How do you protect your site?**

Use HTTPS (that is, HTTP with [TLS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)). If you do it right, a MITM can not read or modify the traffic, and the cryptography can not be brute forced.